# Spoilers and code formatting not working

Tags: bug, design

Please fix that as it does already work on [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/4023/5179) (or show me what I am doing wrong). Thanks in advance.

The following code is *not* hidden when using `>!` hidden/spoiler mark up.

> `Take   to    Taking`
>  `I     see     Your`
>
>  Which reads as "I undertake to oversee your undertaking". You don't allow the word "see" but I assume it's a variation of that....?

Comment: It is hidden on mobile at least, but not on my laptop. Why do we need spoilers discussing WordPress?

Comment: Why not? And aside of it: This is a _bug_.

Comment: AH! Playing hide and seek with obvious answers.